# Are Literary Agents Postponing Their Responses to Queries Thanks to the Coronavirus and Stay-at-Home Orders?

Tags: publishing, agent

I was wondering if it's possible for literary agents to postpone their responses to queries during this time crisis? In major states like New York, they have stay-at-home orders. Is this going to affect the industry as a whole?

Comment: Every industry has been and will be effected. I'd expect every business to be reconsidering their plans for the next 2 years due to economic uncertainty.

Comment: This is bad news.

Answer (score 1):

The Publishing center and literary agents will be affected but they are still receiving submissions and queries. Although the disease is spreading rapidly, interviews on Zoom and submissions on messages are still a beneficial way to get your writing to publish.

Tips: Covid-19 related stories are being avoided since the topic was ongoing throughout the year so you're out of luck writing it.

https://datewiththemuse.com/are-agents-still-open-to-queries-during-covid-19/

Hope this helps!